# Target link multiple libraries in a project on clion

Tags: c++, linux, clion

I am trying to use target_link_libraries in a project on clion, but when i run the project the following error is printed:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lctop_common
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lctop_log
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lctop_util
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -leigen
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrl-algorithm
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrl-loader
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrl-tsplib
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is what my cmakelist file includes:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(planner_standalone_grasp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fno-diagnostics-color")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

# find all cpp files in currect directory (where CMakeLists.txt is)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "./src/*.cpp")


include_directories(src)


add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})

set(EXE_LIBS
    ctop_common
    ctop_log
    ctop_util

    eigen
    crl
    crl-algorithm
    crl-loader
    crl-tsplib
    yaml-cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${EXE_LIBS})
```

... Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

target_link_libraries tells cmake what libraries to link against (the -l flag that is). You have to specify where to find said libraries too! this can be done with target_link_directories... (the -L flag).

If you have these libraries in the lib folder, make sure they are compiled for the same platform as the executable you are trying to build.

I believe on linux you can also drop the libraries in the lib folder and not use the target_link_directories inc make, not sure...

so:
target_link_libraries specifies the names of the libraries,
target_link_directories specifies the directories of these libraries.

Comment: Very much appreciating your response,so actually adding 
target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC lib/comrob/lib/) to my cmakelist fixed the error for the following libraries (crl, crl-algorithm, crl-loader, crl-tsplib) as they exist in the path i specified using "target_link_directories", however the other libraries are located in another directory inside the project, how can i allow it to find them without losing the libraries i was already able to find?

Comment: Glad I could help a bit! You can add as many target_link_directory statements as you want, so you could do something like this: target_link_directories(<exe> PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/path/to/directories), doing ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../ will go up a level.

Comment: Great! Please mark the question, then I get points! :)